# compare NSInteger with sorted NSIntegerArray objectAtIndex

Tags: ios, objective-c, string-comparison

For my High score, I need to display the place in the High score in a label before the sorting is initiated.

So I have a highscoreArray at each objectAtIndex is the name and the points saved like this:

```
2015-06-29 03:08:34.159 Game[3408:838910] (
    {
    name = "TEST-TES";
    points = 250;
},
    {
    name = EEE;
    points = 180;
},
    {
    name = HHHHH;
    points = 90;
},
    {
    name = "ADTES";
    points = 70;
},
    {
    name = EE;
    points = 70;
},
    {
    name = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;
    points = 70;
},
    {
    name = TEEEST;
    points = 40;
},
    {
    name = R;
    points = 20;
},
    {
    name = er;
    points = 20;
},
    {
    name = test1;
    points = 20;
}
)
```

So now for example I finished the game and got 100 points. I will get the 3rd place.

How can I compare my score to the highscoreArray and display in a label the objectAtIndex Number? (in this example: 100 points will be between objectAtIndex: 1 and 2, so I have to be the third place.)

EDIT:

tried:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *highscoreindex;

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
_highscoreindex = [defaults objectForKey:@"highscore"];
NSLog(@"%@", _highscoreindex);


int i;
UIColor *color = [UIColor blackColor];
for (i = 0; i < [_highscoreindex count]; i++) {
    [_highscoreindex objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([_highscoreindex objectAtIndex:0 < self.score]) {
        _highscoreIndexLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DINAlternate-Bold" size:80]];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setTextColor:color];

    }
    if ([_highscoreindex objectAtIndex:0 > self.score]) {
        _highscoreIndexLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2"];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DINAlternate-Bold" size:80]];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setTextColor:color];

    }
    if ([_highscoreindex objectAtIndex:1 > self.score]) {
        _highscoreIndexLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"3"];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DINAlternate-Bold" size:80]];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setTextColor:color];
    }
    if ([_highscoreindex objectAtIndex:2 > self.score]) {
        _highscoreIndexLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"4"];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DINAlternate-Bold" size:80]];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setTextColor:color];
    }
    if ([_highscoreindex objectAtIndex:3 > self.score]) {
        _highscoreIndexLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"5"];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DINAlternate-Bold" size:80]];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setTextColor:color];
    }
    if ([_highscoreindex objectAtIndex:4 > self.score]) {
        _highscoreIndexLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"6"];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DINAlternate-Bold" size:80]];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setTextColor:color];
    }
    if ([_highscoreindex objectAtIndex:5 > self.score]) {
        _highscoreIndexLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"7"];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DINAlternate-Bold" size:80]];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setTextColor:color];
    }
    if ([_highscoreindex objectAtIndex:6 > self.score]) {
        _highscoreIndexLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"8"];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DINAlternate-Bold" size:80]];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setTextColor:color];
    }
    if ([_highscoreindex objectAtIndex:7 > self.score]) {
        _highscoreIndexLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"9"];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DINAlternate-Bold" size:80]];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setTextColor:color];
    }
    if ([_highscoreindex objectAtIndex:8 > self.score]) {
        _highscoreIndexLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"10"];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DINAlternate-Bold" size:80]];
        [_highscoreIndexLabel setTextColor:color];
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to iterate through the array, comparing the value in each dictionary entry break the loop at the appropriate point.  Can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: You should pass the variable i to objectAtIndex: instead of 0,1,2... and your block of "is it greater? is it less?" code should only be written once in the body of the loop. The way that it is now, for however many items are in the array, it will compare the first 9 array items to self.score and change the label many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is an index that iterates through your array, so you don't need all of the separate if statements. Note that I have assumed that `highscoreindex` actually contains `NSNumber`s because you can't store `NSInteger`s in an array

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *highscoreindex;

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.highscoreindex = [defaults objectForKey:@"highscore"];

int i;
UIColor *color = [UIColor blackColor];
for (i = 0; i < self.highscoreindex.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *highScoreDict=(NSDictionary *)self.highscoreindex[i]
    NSInteger highScore=[(NSNumber *)highScoreDict[@"points"] integerValue];
    if (self.score > highScore) {
        self.highscoreIndexLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i+1];
        [self.highscoreIndexLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [self.highscoreIndexLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DINAlternate-Bold" size:80]];
        [self.highscoreIndexLabel setTextColor:color];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I always like your answers

Comment: thank you but i get this error: 2015-06-29 12:12:45.132 Game[17906:585056] -[__NSCFDictionary integerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7feba0707a70
2015-06-29 12:12:45.156 Game[17906:585056] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary integerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7feba0707a70'

Comment: i think the problem is, that in _highscoreIndex is on each objectAtIndex name and points, so he can't compare?

Comment: _highscoreIndex NSLog: 2015-06-29 12:29:42.230 Game[18007:590105] (
        {
        name = EEEE;
        points = 70;
    }
) so an entry in highscore looks like

Comment: I based my answer on your code, but it seems that each element in the array is a dictionary, not an integer as your code suggested.  I will update my answer